# How do I index data sequences in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, sequence

I have an image frame and its mean and variances. I want to access few frames mean and variance simultaneously. In order to do so, I need to index means and variances in each frames.

```
[M V] = mean_var(frame);
```

I have a function that calculates frame's mean and variance. How can I index them as their sequences?

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have a cellarray with your frames

```
frames = { frame1, frame2, ... };
```

You can get mean/variance through

```
[m v] = cellfun( @mean_var, frames );
```

Now you have **vectors** `m` and `v` with `numel(frames)` elements holding the mean and variance of the frames.